# objective-c - How to add multiple images to an array shown on a label?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, image

I am trying to show sometimes photos and sometimes facts in a label. For that I've an array with facts in my .m file including an arcm4 for randomly generated content.

```
- (instancetype) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _Facts = @[
                   @"The length of an elephant is the same as the tongue of a blue whale.",
                   @"The crocodile’s tongue is unmovable, as it is attached to the roof of its mouth."
                   ];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)populateLabel:(UILabel *)Label {
    int random = arc4random_uniform(@(_aFacts.count).intValue);
    NSObject * element = _aFacts[random];
    if ([element isKindOfClass:NSString.class]) {
        //        NSLog(@"Will add string");
        Label.attributedText = nil;
        Label.text = (NSString*) element;
    } else if ([element isKindOfClass:NSAttributedString.class]) {
        //        NSLog(@"Will add image");
        Label.text = nil;
        Label.attributedText = (NSAttributedString*)element;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"_aFacts array is supposed to contain only NSString(s) and NSAttributedString(s). Instead a %@ has been found at index %d", NSStringFromClass(element.class), random);
    }
}
```

Then I wanted to also include images by adding this code:

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
attachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"196H"];
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];
```

And at the and of the array after the last item this:

```
, attributedString
```

I'm calling this code in my viewController file:

```
[self.aFactBook populateLabel:self.Label];
```

So this code works well but

1. I need to include over 200+ images
2. Is there any better solution than working like this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how much performance means to you. Sometimes it is really worthy to cache 200 images so you can operate them well, sometimes 200 images could be extended to 10 000 images and then you'd want to store  their names and load them only when needed instead of keeping all of them in memory.

Maybe you should consider using something like database whether it is SQLite or CoreData.

Comment: What would you recommend me? Of course I'd like to extend the app to more than 400 images but I don't have any experience with core data nor with SQLite. Do you know some tutorials or could show me some code?

Comment: Well if you are thinking of extending your app's facts base you really should use a database. CoreData may be a little complicated to start with, but performance is very high. I love Brian Advent's tutorials, he even got one for CoreData http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jootsUaCvAU. But you wont face any problems trying to find tutorials in web. There is not way to provide a code samples for such a broad purpose.

Comment: If core data is better than I'd use it. But can I convert this existing project to work with core data?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to keep your data is to use databases. I personally recommend SQLite, it is very easy and powerful DMS. Also, if you need further expand in the future with the database you will not need to change the code ,just the database's records.

You can use BLOB( data type ) for images and VARCHAR for your facts( those data types are for the building of the database's table.

If you are satisfy with my answer, don't forget to thumb up!